# Creating a loop for user selected range

Tags: excel, vba

Developing a code through which user selects a range in the active workbook. For the range selected i.e. A8:A12 i want to run a loop through which for each range in the selected range, the loop takes its value, Filters GL_Sheet's Current Region (GL_Rng) using that value and copy's the visible cells
The code is

```
'Declaring Workbooks
Dim GL_CY As Variant
Dim GL_Book As Workbook, Tgt_Book As Workbook
GL_CY = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Open GL", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
Set GL_Book = Application.Workbooks.Open(GL_CY)
Set Tgt_Book = Workbooks.Add


'Selecting Range
Dim GL_Code As Variant, GL_LR As Long, GL_Rng As range, Rng As range
Dim GL_Sheet As Worksheet, tgt As Worksheet
Set GL_Sheet = GL_Book.Worksheets(1)
GL_LR = GL_Sheet.range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set GL_Rng = GL_Sheet.range("A4:R" & GL_LR).CurrentRegion.Offset(3, 0)
GL_Code = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the range of GL codes to generate its GL activity ", Title:="Generate GL Activity", Type:=8)
' GL_Sheet.range("A3:A5").Value = range(GL_Code).Value



For Each Rng In range(GL_Code)
    Set tgt = Tgt_Book.Worksheets.Add
    GL_Rng.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=GL_Code
    GL_Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    tgt.Paste
    tgt.range("A1").CurrentRegion.Cut tgt.range("B6")
    tgt.Cells.WrapText = False
    tgt.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    tgt.Name = GL_Code
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Next Rng
```

As you can see I am struggling with the last part of the code which results in Error 1004 (Method of range...)

Comment: At a minimum, GL_Rng.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=GL_Code should use Rng not GL_Code.

Comment: will correct that, any suggestions regarding the main issue?

Comment: Not sure, which line gives you the error?

Comment: "For Each Rng In range(GL_Code)"

Comment: Maybe try `Dim GL_Code As Range` then in `GL_Code = Application.InputBox` put Set ---> `Set GL_Code = Application.InputBox....`. Then finally `For Each Rng In GL_Code` ... `Criteria1:=Rng.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naqi,

I created a little test routine to check out what was being returned from the InputBox.
Turns it was coming back as a Variant. I tried setting it as a Range but that wouldn't work either. However changing the Type:=2 (string) makes it work

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim GL_Code As String

GL_Code = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the range of GL codes to generate its GL activity ", _
                               Title:="Generate GL Activity", _
                               Type:=2)
                               
Debug.Print Range(GL_Code).Address()

End Sub

'So by changing your Type to 2 the For Each rng statement should no longer create a problem.

Edit: Found an option using Type 8:
[Click here for the post I found this in.][1]

Sub MyMacro()

Dim GL_Code As Range
Set GL_Code = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)

Debug.Print GL_Code.Address()

End Sub

'Since GL_Code is now a range your For Each should NOT enclose it in a Range() function!
```

HTH

Comment: thanks
Does the trick, declared GL_Code as a variant resulting in the error